# setValue:forKey: with a NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I'm currently working on a small and specific iPhone app to connect to a server and download some JSON data. My problem is about a property list I use to save some data (login, password and domain of the server). I've easily created the plist in Xcode but when I try to edit it with the texts entered by the user, I'm having a problem and I don't know how to fix it ...

Here is the `textFieldDidEndEditing: method`, in which I try to write to the plist, with what the user have written in a domainTextField :

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/userInfo.plist", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filepath];

    if (self.domainTextField) {
        NSString *domain = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.domainTextField.text];
        [userInfo setValue:domain forKey:@"domain"];
    }

    if ([userInfo writeToFile:filepath atomically:TRUE]) {
        NSLog(@"write succeeded");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"write failed");
    }
}
```

I'm always receiving a "write failed" error here and after playing a bit with the debugger, I found that the problem is with the `setValue:forKey: method`. In fact, I expect this method to write that in the plist : `domain = "whateverthedomainis"` because `domain` is a NSString but it writes instead : `domain = whateverthedomainis`. And as the writeToFile:atomically: method makes sure that all the objects are property list objects, it returns NO. I tried to put backslashes, but that didn't help.

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: I think you may need to escaped that string, I would use the binary saving method instead of plist one

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try the binary method, but I'd be surprised their is no way to do this without binary

Comment: Have you tried using the `NSMutableDictionary` method `setObject:forKey:` instead, rather than Key-Value-Coding?

Comment: I've just tried it and the result is weird : `[userInfo writeToFile:filepath atomically:TRUE]` looks like to be YES because I have the `NSLog(@"write succeeded");` but when I check on the plist, the new domain is not set ...

Answer (score 0):

StringWithFormat will use if you have any arguments in a string so you can directly assign a string value ,like  this

```
NSString *domain = self.domainTextField.text;
```

Comment: Right the stringWithFormat was useless, but it doesn't resolve my error. Thanks anyway